# Avoiding malformed images serving raster data from GeoServer with a Geopackage store

Tags: raster, geoserver, geopackage

I'm attempting to use the Geopackage format to serve raster data in GeoServer 2.21.0 (OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu) and am getting odd results when using layer preview or WMS GetMap to view the data.

(Since I can't share my actual data yet I've contrived an example using a generated [prettymap](https://github.com/marceloprates/prettymaps) but the result is the same.)

My starting point is a GeoTIFF that looks like this (which is roughly georeferenced):

[image: The original map]

I'm converting this to a Geopackage using `gdal_translate` like so:

```
gdal_translate -of GPKG mymap.tif mymap.gpkg
```

The output looks fine to me and I can open the Geopackage fine in QGIS. I can also inspect it in SQLite Browser and see that `gdal_translate` has broken the image up into a set of 256x256 tiles, which all look fine.

I'm then importing this Geopackage into GeoServer using the REST API like so:

```
curl -uadmin:geoserver -XPUT \
     -Haccept:application/json -Hcontent-type:application/x-sqlite3 \
     --data-binary @mymap.gpkg \
     "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myws/coveragestores/mymap/file.geopackage (mosaic)"
```

Everything looks good in the Geoserver UI. But when I try and view the data I get this broken map out:

[image: The Geoserver WMS layer preview]

The common thing with the output images is that some of the outside tiles (e.g. top row and left row) are rendered correctly, but the inner tiles seem to be single colour blocks of hues belonging to some pixel in the tile.

The only way I can get Geopackages to render "correctly" is to generate them with the `-co BLOCKSIZE=...` option greater than the image dimensions so there's only a single tile, but this seems sub-optimal.

Has anyone come across this issue or know of a configuration problem that might cause it. I have already looked at the list of open or recently-fixed GeoServer issues and I can't see this specific problem .

*Specs*: GeoServer 2.21.0, openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19, Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04.

Comment: do you set the projection of your data and the extent correctly

Comment: also does it work if you just use the geotiff as the raster input rather than pushing it into a geopackage? and does the problem persist if you use the GUI instead of REST to create the layer

Comment: Hi Ian - thanks for your help. Nothing wrong with the projection and extent as far as I can see and the Geopackage looks fine in QGIS. GeoTiff as raster layer also looks fine. And I have tried adding the store and layer via the UI and indeed get the same (bad) result.

Comment: then it may be a bug but we'll need a link to a geopackage that generates the issue to inversigate

Comment: GeoTiff and Geopackage can be found here: https://github.com/mikesname/geoserver_test

Both look fine in QGIS unless I'm doing something silly somewhere...

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to take this one to the mailing list. Mostly I'm seeing a disagreement between GeoServer/GDAL which thinks the SRS is 3857 and QGIS which thinks (wrongly) that it's wgs84. It might be a format issue or a tile scheme issue and I don't know enough about those to comment

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm worried that SRS issue might be due to my georeferencing (in QGIS) of this test map, but the issue does occur for me on any GeoTiff I convert, including those I didn't make. I haven't played around with non-default tile schemes yet so I might give that a try first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not a complete answer I want to post the best workaround I can currently find. That is to use JPEG instead of PNG format tiles. GDAL's default is to use a [mix of PNG and JPEG tiles depending on transparency and whether or not the tiles are full size or clipped](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html#raster-gpkg-tile-formats).

Doing some experimentation I have found that PNG tiles only render correctly when none of them are clipped, i.e. the full image is an even multiple of the tile size.

So for the example in the question I would convert from TIFF to Geopackage using the following command:

```
gdal_translate -of GPKG -co TILE_FORMAT=JPEG mymap.tif mymap.gpkg
```

The actual reason for this is unclear and would require some investigation of how the Geopackage reader in GeoTools works.